# Semi-colon goes to centre after return in elisp buffer

Tags: emacs, elisp

I just started having a problem with semi-colons in elisp buffers. I enter a semi-colon, ';', and hit return at which point the semi-colon gets centered. I am running the Gnu for OS X build :-

This is GNU Emacs 24.4.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0, NS apple-appkit-1265.21)
 of 2014-10-21 on builder10-9.porkrind.org

I am running it on OX X 10.10. It only started happening so I removed my .emacs file and my .emacs.d directory and it still keeps happening.

It was working fine and then when I was installing some packages to do Python work it went crazy and nothing will get it back to OK. I even redownloaded the App.

Any ideas?

// Tony Williams

Comment: What mode is your elisp buffer in? It should be in Lisp Interaction mode.

Comment: It's in Emacs-Lisp mode according to the Mode line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the buffer is in Emacs-Lisp mode and `electric-indent-mode`, which was introduced in emacs 24.1, is enabled, then the described indentation behavior is what you'd expect to see because a single `;` by default indents to `comment-column`. And note that unlike prior versions, emacs 24.4 enables `electric-indent-mode` by default.

Comment: +1. Now that you mention it, I'm reading the question differently, and I think that is what the OP was trying to describe. The answer, of course, is to just disable `electric-indent-mode`, by default. ;-) I did that as soon as I found out about this "feature": `(when (fboundp 'electric-indent-mode) (electric-indent-mode -1))`

Comment: AHHH, a single semi-colon does that while a double sticks were it is!! Thank you!! That was my answer.